# Webpack unable to load module for karma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, karma-jasmine

Tyring to use webpack to bundle my depenedencies to be used in karma spec files. But getting:

`Module 'fuse' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Fuse is the name of ng-app.

this same setup works when I run on standard tests, but when I try to: `beforeEach(module('fuse'));` the app breaks with the above error.

Here is my Karma.conf:

```
// Karma configuration
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.dev.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = {};
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: false,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    autoWatchBatchDelay: 300,
    // ... normal karma configuration
    files: [



      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      // 'public/app/pages/main/**/*.spec.js',

      '../../app.js',
      'public/app/services/auth/auth_service.spec.js'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      // add webpack as preprocessor
      '../../app.js': ['webpack'],
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
      // i. e.
      noInfo: true
    },

    plugins: [
      require("karma-webpack"),
      require("karma-jasmine"),
      require("karma-chrome-launcher"),
      require("karma-phantomjs-launcher")

    ]
  });
};
```

Any idea what is going on? I've tried so many things and am almost out of ideas, will keep trying to reorder the files being loaded.

Comment: -Did you get answer for this? I am getting somewhat similar issue with webpack. I am unable to load angularjs module. I get this error  :-             This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.

Comment: I did not, I did learn never to use webpack in a rails project though